# latex compiler hangs, no error message shown

Tags: compiling, kile

When I am compiling my .tex file using Kile GUI, if there is no syntax error in my .tex file then it works properly and show a message that there is no error.

But latex compiler hangs if there is
any syntax error in my .tex file and does not show any error message. How can I see the error messages. Should I have to add some package?

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too little information to be able to give any advice. What exactly are you trying to compile? What OS do you use? What installation of LaTeX? etc.

Comment: Do you not have a "Log and messages" panel at the bottom of your screen? Does selecting Settings --> Show Messages Bar help?

Comment: It may be going into an infinite loop. TeX itself has a loop detector, but if the looping is happening outside that, it may look as if it has hung. Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates the behaviour?