# kile hangs and no error messages are shown

Tags: kile

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. When I use kile (with TeX Live), everything works as long as there is no error.  However, if there is an error, kile does not show the errors and it just hangs.  Any ideas on what the problem may be?

There was a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36313/latex-compiler-hangs-no-error-message-shown) before, but it was closed.

For instance, the following code hangs in my kile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Text $f
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I think this is more something you should ask in a Kile mailing list and, if you are sure is a bug, report to the maintainers. It is not a LaTeX problem per se, I don't think.

Comment: As far as i know, Kile has an internal terminal to interact with TeX. Does it do it this time? Check texworks, the free editor does it the same way.